# AWS push notification not sending | SNS and Pinpoint | Android Studio FCM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, push-notification, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint

I'm unable to receive any of my push notifications sent by either Amazon SNS or Pinpoint. At one point it used to work via the push notification section on AWS however has stopped for some reason. I've tried using pinpoint via a lambda function for it to work but to no avail. I should add also that Pinpoint is my preferred method for sending the push notifications via lambda, as the goal for my project is to have triggered push notifications.

[Lambda function using pinpoint to send push notifcation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ9MI.png)

I'm using Android Studio and I wonder if the problem lies there? as I am using the correct token that my android studio app received so the issue isn't there.

[Picture of my token in the android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zMS0.png)
[Proof of token used in AWS SNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99UWO.png)

Does anyone know what it may be? I would greatly appreciate any help received

Also if anyone knows how to send a notification to all users of my app that would be brilliant.

Comment: Are you trying to use the AWS SDK for Java in an Android Studio project? Can you please reference the AWS docs you are following to implement this solution. It will help

Comment: [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/send-messages-push.html) this is what i was using for the pinpoint.

[link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-application-as-subscriber.html) And I was using this for the SNS push notification

Comment: Apologies for the long reply